# Openvswitch portnumber to controller

Tags: opendaylight, openvswitch, sdn

Does anyone know how do I see what is the port number of openvswitch that is being connected to the opendaylight controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use wireshark or any other traffic sniffers on the interface connecting the switch to the controller (if the controller is in the same physical machine as the openvswitch then you should sniff the loopback interface)
- Or, use netstat -a | grep [the port number of the controller, likely 6633 or 6653]. You find the port number of the switch in the same line